# how can I color an item in listview in xamarin native android

Tags: android, xamarin, android-listview

I want to change the color of an item in a listview in Xamarin Android.

This is my code:

```
mlistView = FindViewById<ListView>(Resource.Id.lista_clientes);

mItems = new List<string>();

for (int i = 0; i < dt_lista.Rows.Count; i++)
{

mItems.Add(dt_lista.Rows[i][1].ToString());

}

mAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<string>(this, Android.Resource.Layout.SimpleListItem1, mItems);
mlistView.Adapter = mAdapter;
```

Answer (score 0):

private void changeTheColor(ListView listView, int position) { listView.getChildAt(position).setBackgroundColor(Color.*); }